# Skip array values in php with condition

Tags: php, arrays, skip

I have a small script:

```
    <?php
    function skip_value()
    {
       for ($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
       {
           echo $i.' ';
           if ($i==1) sleep(5);
           if ($i==2) sleep(10);
           if ($i==3) sleep(7);
       }
    }
    skip_value();
    ?>
```

Expected result: `0 1 2 3 4`

When running, `i`'s values are: 0 1 3 4 (This mean is if time execute >7 then skip a command line that )  My problem is execution time of each loop

Comment: Are you asking, How long in seconds will it take to execute each iteration of the loop from iteration 0 to 4?

Comment: Thanks you help me eddited :D, time to excute each iteration of the loop is different, so that i use sleep($second) to example :)

Comment: Your question isn't clear - Do you want to miss an iteration if $i is equal to 1,2 or 3. your code should produce 0 1 2 3 4 as it is.

Comment: All that the sleep does is delay the output

Comment: I just ran that code and it produced 0 1 2 3 4, what are you trying to do

Comment: but you are first printing and then delaying. Why not do vice-versa ? Or if you want to skip value use continue right after sleep

Comment: I can description like this.
i=0 (excute time is 5s) 
 i=1 (excute time is 3s)
 i=2 (excute time is 10s)
 i=4 (excute time is 5s)
And in each loop i check time excute if time()>7s, skip it

Comment: just curious how do you check if time() > 7 :D

Comment: I have a loop, when running, each values in loop output very very long. I want to skip it if excute time of each values very long :(

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 function skip_value()
 {
       for ($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
       {
           if ($i==1) sleep(5);
           if ($i==2) {sleep(10); continue; } //continue if its 2, skip 2
           if ($i==3) sleep(7);

           echo $i.' '; //print
       }
 }
 skip_value();
```

will produce `0 1 3 4`.

Your question is kind of unclear, so I assume thats what you want.

Comment: Thanks for code, but i not like my idea: just i want to caculator time execute of each values in loop, if that time > $second, stop excute and skip thats value, then continue loop with next value. I used sleep just an example  :D